# How to use INTERVAL in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, intervals, cakephp-3.x

I am using CakePHP 3.x. I have converted and stored all my dates to string using the `strtotime(date('Y/m/d h:i', time()));`  .And in DB it will store like this **1479466560** But Right now i need to select rows from exactly 14 days ago. I tried like below conditions,

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$userList = $this->Users->find('all')
    ->select(['created'])
    ->where(['status' => 1,'created' => 'created + INTERVAL 14 DAY > NOW()']);
```

It is returning empty rows only. How to do this ?. Can any one help me !

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not tell you how to use `interval` but it does solve the problem.

What I've done in the past is a simple `>=` `<` combination together with php variables:

```
$cur_date = date_create();
$date = clone $cur_date;
$date->modify("-12 hours");

$this->Model->find()
    ->where(['created >= ' => $date])
    ->andWhere(['created < '=> $cur_date]);
```

This effectively uses an interval. It is also nicely dynamically editable.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't match with any `created` date from your `users` table.

**Your CakePHP3 query generated below SQL:**

```
SELECT created FROM users WHERE (status = 1 AND created = created + INTERVAL 14 DAY > NOW())
```

> **Note:** At First try and adjust above query from your `phpmyadmin`.

**You can try below SQL for `INTERVAL` test**

```
SELECT '2016-01-17 10:57:21' + INTERVAL 14 DAY > NOW();
```

**OR**

```
SELECT '2016-01-17 10:57:21' + INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

> **Note:** Adjust date string as you need. Now you can see what is the `wrong` you have done